# What is the name of this statistical interaction?

Tags: feature-selection, probability, theory

What is the name of the following statistical / informational interaction:

given A, I know exactly what B is.
given B, I know to some extent what A is.

I'm not looking for a probability but rather something like correlation.
Something that tells me that I don't need to include B as a feature when A
is already a feature. A correlation heatmap wouldn't give me this information, but there must be some computation that tells me "Don't include B, it's worthless."

To give some intuition: A could be an item_id and B an item_category.

Or am I wrong? Is it not worthless at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at [conditional entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_entropy), H(A|B) and H(B|A).

Comment: Thank you. Will this be useful for feature selection?

Comment: Assuming you can calculate those values (which means you have access to the marginals P(A), P(B), P(A,B) or a reasonable estimate thereof), yes. Given the two features A and B, if H(A|B) is low, you can use B as a feature and ignore A. Whether these computations are feasible is a separate question.

Comment: Also, your ML model might benefit from having both, even if there's not technically any additional information there.